# GitLab CI failing with @angular/cli

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm trying to deploy a Angular 4 app to Firebase using GitLab CI but it's failing.

Here is my CI configuration:

```
image: node:latest

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

stages:
  - setup
  - build
  - deploy

setup:
  stage: setup
  script:
    - npm install
  only:
    - master

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install -g @angular/cli
    - ng build -prod
  only:
    - master

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - npm install -g @angular/cli
    - npm install -g firebase-tools
    - ng build -prod
    - firebase use --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY production
    - firebase deploy -m "Pipeline $CI_PIPELINE_ID, build $CI_BUILD_ID" --non-interactive --token $FIREBASE_DEPLOY_KEY
  only:
    - master
```

It's failing at the build stage, i think it's cause the @angular/cli install command.

Also, there is the log of the build stage: http://pasted.co/8d06985e

Comment: Really what do u want? and what kind of project? Why don't u use dockers  in your CI/CD?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some reason, globally installed packages are not added to the PATH and not available. What I'm doing is using relative paths (with recent versions of np executables like `ng` are installed in the `node_modules/.bin` subfolder)

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install @angular/cli
    - ./node_modules/.bin/ng build -prod
```

Answer (score 2):

You should configure the build script in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build --prod",
},
```

Since you are running `npm install` already in your setup stage, you should not run `npm install -g @angular/cli` in your build stage. Instead, simply invoke the build script:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
```

This way you can avoid creating build on every stage and use your local Angular CLI which you've already downloaded in setup stage.

Alternatively, if you dont want to add a build script in `package.json`, you can still leverage the local Angular CLI directly in the build stage as follows:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run ng -- build --prod
```

This is admittedly a bit ugly but it does help avoid reinstall of Angular CLI globally.

A less ugly version of above script (using `npx`, applicable only for node > 5.2) is as follows:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npx ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not hardcode the path use $(npm bin) instead... it will produce the path to the closes bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

if u use angular project, below code is enough in your script

```
script:
- apk add --no-cache git
- npm install
- npm install -g bower
- bower install --allow-root
- npm run-script build
```

npm install already install all libraries in your `package.json`

Comment: This is an incomplete answer and also requires Bower, which is not a given with Angular cli.