# ng version not working in deployment server

Tags: node.js, angular

On my deployment server, I have installed Angular with the following command

```
npm install –g @angular/cli
```

I also have install Yarn similarly.

Verified that the angular files does exist in c:\user\username\appdata\roaming\npm folder.

If I run `ng version` then it shows correct version, however when I tried to deploy using GitLab runner, it says that `ng is not recognized`. I restarted the server after installation, but no luck.
Surprisingly, `yarn version` and `node -v` does work form GitLab, it's just `ng version` is not working. any idea?

Comment: can it be related to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269681/gitlab-ci-failing-with-angular-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269681/gitlab-ci-failing-with-angular-cli) ?